# How important is it to use a Mobil 1 oil filter if you are using Mobil 1 engine oil?

Tags: oil, oil-change, oil-filter

It seems like some oil changing stores do not use a Mobil 1 oil filter even if they use Mobil 1 engine oil. When using Mobil 1 engine oil, is it much better to use a Mobil 1 oil filter?

Answer (score 5):

No, but using a quality part for your engine is. Some “cheap” filters may not have the performance or longevity of a quality filter.

Really, a “cheap” filter is poor economy considering the function of the filter and the cost of an engine.

This applies to fuel filters as well.

Use a quality brand - there are several...

Comment: Can't vote this up enough. Cheap filters meet the bare minimum of standards. More expensive ones from trust brands (such as Blue Print, especially with Japanese cars) tend to be built more to the specification of the original OEM parts. Where as Crossland or Wix filters tend to just meet the generic industry standard.

Comment: Perfect answer. OEM filters from the dealer are often surprisingly cost-effective (e.g genuine Subaru filters are cheaper from the dealer than from car parts stores)